# Show div based on url

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to find a short and easy to understand javascript that show a div based on the URL but all scripts I find doesn't seem to work.

I have this div on my page and the css file hides the div with: display:none;

```
<div id="idofthedivtohide"><span>Success!</span></div>
```

When I go to url: contact.php?success I want the div to change to display: block;

Can someone help me with this? Many examples make it work with like 4 lines of code.

I've tried this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.search.search(success)) document.getElementById("idofthedivtohide").style.display = "block"
</script>
```

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried so far?  Please post your attempts.

Comment: Paste the HTML, select the HTML code and press CTRL+K.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another solution, more "human friendly":

**HTML**

```
<div id="idofthedivtohide">
  <span>Success!</span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Get URL
  var url = window.location.href;
  // Get DIV
  var msg = document.getElementById('idofthedivtohide');
  // Check if URL contains the keyword
  if( url.search( 'success' ) > 0 ) {
      // Display the message
      msg.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Great! But how can i call success in URL ??

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="success"><span>Success!</span></div>
```

```
var locSearch = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&')[0];
if(locSearch){
    document.getElementById( locSearch ).style.display = "block";
}
```

The above will handle

```
http://example.exm/page.html?success  // success
```

same as

```
http://example.exm/page.html?success&user=2971024&votes=0 // success
```

Comment: Cool, it worked, thanks!

How do the code find ?success in the URL? Can't find the word success in it, magic?

Comment: @user2971024 yes ;) (search MDN for the methods you don't know: substring, split etc...) and BTW, the above might throw an error if you have eg: `?error` bot you don't have any `#error` element in your page. so take care or add an `if()` to check for element existence.

Answer (score 0):

We can execute this problem with this simple javascript function. To show a div based on the URL we can use the javascript 'window.location' object to get the current URL and then use an if statement to determine if the URL meets conditions to show or hide a div or any element.

```js
function showDiv() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("success") != -1) {
      document.getElementById("idofthedivtohide").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("idofthedivtohide").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

```html
<body onload="showDiv()">
  <div id="idofthedivtohide" style="display: none;">This is a div that will only be shown on the page where the page's URL contains "success" </div>
</body>
```

It will handle

```
contact.php?success
```

or

```
contact.php?!@#$success!@#$
```